Tab Navigation In MAUI Is Not Showing The Back Button
I have AppShell.xaml as below,
<Shell>
    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Home">
            <Tab.Icon>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeLightIcons"
                                 Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeLightIcons.House}" />
            </Tab.Icon>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Home">
            <Tab.Icon>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeLightIcons"
                                 Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeLightIcons.House}" />
            </Tab.Icon>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage2}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>

In AppShell.xaml.cs,
Routing.RegisterRoute("MainPage", typeof(MainPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute("MainPage2", typeof(MainPage2));

I am opening the application and MainPage will be loaded. I am navigating to the MainPage2 by clicking on the shell tab. The MainPage2 will be rendered. But, I can't see the back button on the top left of the page.
If I navigating to the MainPage2 by clicking on the button Shell.Current.GoToAsync("MainPage2") inside MainPage, Then the back button is visible.
How can I forcefully show the back button while navigating by using shell tabs?

clicking on the shell tab will set the tab selected as root page of the Navigation Stack.

Same issue I was facing, then change to INavigation for navigation and started using tabbed page.
